# How to detect and track object changes in JS?

Tags: javascript

I want to keep an history of changes made to an entity. For example, user entity:

```
{
  name: 'Raz',
  places_visited: [
    { city: 'Jerusalem', street: 'King David', house_number: 10 }
  ]
}
```

Then these kind of changes may apply:

1. name 'Raz' has updated to 'Raziel'
2. The first place he visited has updated from house_number 10 to house_number 20
3. A new place has been inserted on top (he visited this place before the place that he had already visited, like **unshift**): `{ city: 'Tel Aviv', street: 'Ibn Gabirol', house_number: 30 }`

I want to store those changes somehow, probably in the DB in a dedicated History collection that will store just any changes, regardless the user entity. The history collection may look like this and have these fields:

EntityType, EntityId, KeyChanged, OldValue, NewValue, ...(IAT and By and etc)

So in our case, the history collection should contain the next 4 rows:

1. user, 123, name, Raz, Raziel, today, by admin
2. user, 123, places_visited.0.house_number, 10, 20, today, by admin
3. user, 123, places_visited.0, `{ city: 'Jerusalem', street: 'King David', house_number: 20 }`, `{ city: 'Tel Aviv', street: 'Ibn Gabiron', house_number: 30 }`, today, by admin,
4. user, 123, places_visited.1, undefined, `{ city: 'Jerusalem', street: 'King David', house_number: 20 }`, today, by admin

I have tried to use the JS new built in Proxy class:

```
const handler = {
  get(target, prop) {
    if (typeof target[prop] === "object" && target[prop] !== null) {
      handler.prefix += `${prop}.`
      return new Proxy(target[prop], handler)
    }
    return target[prop]
  },
  set(target, prop, newValue) {
    const oldValue = target[prop]
    target[prop] = newValue
    if (oldValue !== newValue) {
      console.log(oldValue, newValue)
    }
    return true
  }
}

const proxy = new Proxy(user, handler)
```

However, when using methods like `push`, `unshift` or so, are getting messy and the tracking is getting ruined. Also, the "condenced" style is not applying, like the "places_visited.0" - just the primitive value instead.

How this can be achieved?

Answer (score 0):

**Basic**:

For simpler applications, you could set watchpoints in the Sources tab (top of the left pane) in the DevTools window on Chrome (accessible via Inspect on the right-click menu), though this has the downside of needing to watch the objects manually within closures.  That may be good enough as a quick check for your use case if you're well-aware of when and how in the code the object changes.

---

**Intermediate:**

If you want to get into more longitudinal tracking of object changes (including mutations), a teammate recently introduced me to the [Redux DevTools extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/redux-devtools/lmhkpmbekcpmknklioeibfkpmmfibljd?hl=en) for Chrome, FireFox, and subsequent forks of these two browsers.  As an extension, it's a more lightweight version of the [NPM package of the same name](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-devtools) that doesn't require installation in your yarn, etc. assembly.

Note that it was designed and is most helpful for Redux, but per the [documentation](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-devtools/tree/main/extension), it's possible to use with other frameworks as well.

---

**Advanced:**

The more advanced capabilities provided by a [full install of the redux-devtools package](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-devtools/blob/main/docs/Walkthrough.md#installation) give access to customizable monitors tuneable to a variety of components, allowing you to orchestrate debug-level logging within normal runtime operation of the app.

Comment: @Raz - if I had to guess, your case would probably best be served with the Intermediate-level suggestion here if your observations only necessitate the monitoring of a single Object over a well-defined cycle.  If you have a large number of concurrent objects, I'd suggest Advanced monitoring/logging and dumping the records into a lightweight database for analysis.